# Getting different results from the same function inside and outside a mutate function call

Tags: r, function, dplyr

Can someone explain to me why I get a different result when I run the `convertToDisplayTime` function inside mutate than when I run it on its own? The correct result is the one I obtain when I run it on its own. Also, why do I get these warnings? It feels like I might be passing the whole `timeInSeconds` column as an argument when I call `convertToDisplayTime` in the mutate function, but I'm not sure that I really understand the mechanics in play here.

```r
library('tidyverse')
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.1.2

convertToDisplayTime <- function(timeInSeconds){
   ## Takes a time in seconds and converts it
   ## to a xx:xx:xx string format
   
   if(timeInSeconds>86400){   #Not handling time over a day
      stop(simpleError("Enter a time below 86400 seconds (1 day)"))
   } else if(timeInSeconds>3600){
      numberOfMinutes = 0
      numberOfHours = timeInSeconds%/%3600
      remainingSeconds = timeInSeconds%%3600
      
      if(remainingSeconds>60){
         numberOfMinutes = remainingSeconds%/%60
         remainingSeconds = remainingSeconds%%60
      }
      
      if(numberOfMinutes<10){displayMinutes = paste0("0",numberOfMinutes)} 
      else{displayMinutes = numberOfMinutes}
      
      remainingSeconds = round(remainingSeconds)
      if(remainingSeconds<10){displaySeconds = paste0("0",remainingSeconds)} 
      else{displaySeconds = remainingSeconds}
      
      return(paste0(numberOfHours,":",displayMinutes,":", displaySeconds))
      
   } else if(timeInSeconds>60){
      numberOfMinutes = timeInSeconds%/%60
      remainingSeconds = timeInSeconds%%60
      
      remainingSeconds = round(remainingSeconds)
      if(remainingSeconds<10){displaySeconds = paste0("0",remainingSeconds)} 
      else{displaySeconds = remainingSeconds}
      
      return(paste0(numberOfMinutes,":", displaySeconds))
      
   } else{
      return(paste0("0:",timeInSeconds))
   }
}


(df <- tibble(timeInSeconds = c(2710.46, 2705.04, 2691.66, 2708.10)) %>% mutate(displayTime = convertToDisplayTime(timeInSeconds)))
#> Warning in if (timeInSeconds > 86400) {: the condition has length > 1 and only
#> the first element will be used
#> Warning in if (timeInSeconds > 3600) {: the condition has length > 1 and only
#> the first element will be used
#> Warning in if (timeInSeconds > 60) {: the condition has length > 1 and only the
#> first element will be used
#> Warning in if (remainingSeconds < 10) {: the condition has length > 1 and only
#> the first element will be used
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   timeInSeconds displayTime
#>           <dbl> <chr>      
#> 1         2710. 45:10      
#> 2         2705. 45:5       
#> 3         2692. 44:52      
#> 4         2708. 45:8


convertToDisplayTime(2710.46)
#> [1] "45:10"
convertToDisplayTime(2705.04)
#> [1] "45:05"
convertToDisplayTime(2691.66)
#> [1] "44:52"
convertToDisplayTime(2708.10)
#> [1] "45:08"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Your function is not vectorized - that is it only works with a single value at a time and doesn't work correctly with multiple values - so nothing to do with `mutate()` per se - doing `convertToDisplayTime(c(2710.46, 2705.04, 2691.66, 2708.10))` also returns the incorrect result.  It should be rewritten to be vectorized, but a quick fix is `Vectorize(convertToDisplayTime)(c(2710.46, 2705.04, 2691.66, 2708.10))`.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Can you put that into an answer? Seems like it addreses the question fully.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the comments, the problem here is that your function is not vectorized: it works with a single value for an input and outputs a single value. However, this does not work when the input is a vector of values, hence the **`condition has length 1`** warning you get:

```
1: Problem with `mutate()` column `displayTime`.\
ℹ `displayTime = convertToDisplayTime(timeInSeconds)`.  
ℹ the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Here, when you use `dplyr::mutate`, you're technically trying to feed a vector to your function, which is not formatted to process it.

Several options you may consider:

**1. The "fast and ugly" way:**

```
df <- data.frame(timeInSeconds = c(2710.46, 2705.04, 2691.66, 2708.10))

## This one does not work
df %>% mutate(displayTime = convertToDisplayTime(timeInSeconds))

## This one works
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(displayTime = convertToDisplayTime(timeInSeconds)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

`dplyr::rowwise()` allows `dplyr::mutate()` to work on each row independently, rather than by columns. I assume this is the behavior you initially expected. `dplyr::ungroup()` sorta reverts rowwise, eg. go back to the default column-wise behavior.
I may be a little harsh on this one, but this is the kind of trick that I used back when I did not quite understand my way around dataframes and their manipulation...

**2. Vectorize directly from your `dplyr` verbs:**

```
df %>% 
  mutate(displayTime = base::mapply(convertToDisplayTime, timeInSeconds))
## or
df %>% 
  mutate(displayTime = purrr::map_chr(timeInSeconds, convertToDisplayTime))
```

Both options are similar.

**3. Vectorize your function:**

```
convertToDisplayTime_vec <- base::Vectorize(convertToDisplayTime)
# class(convertToDisplayTime_vec)

df %>% mutate(displayTime = convertToDisplayTime_vec(timeInSeconds))

## or
convertToDisplayTime_vec2 <- function(timeInSeconds_vec) {
  mapply(FUN = convertToDisplayTime, timeInSeconds_vec)
}
# class(convertToDisplayTime_vec2)

df %>% 
  mutate(displayTime = convertToDisplayTime_vec2(timeInSeconds))

# Still works on single variables!
# convertToDisplayTime_vec2(6475)
```

This is my favourite option, as once it is implemented you can use it either on single variables, vectors or dataframes, without worring about it.

A little [documentation](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/loop-functions.html) to dig a little into the subject.

PS: As an aside, a little tip worth remembering: you may want to be careful when manipulating `data.frame` and `tibble` objects. Despite their similarity, they have slight differences, and some functions deal differently with one or the other, or actually convert one to the other without your noticing...

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This was really clear and helped me a lot. I indeed assumed that mutate worked on each row independently.