# Adding ggplot output to a tibble using mutate() only adds result from first plot

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm attempting to add a ggplot to each row in a tibble.  But whilst I can see that the plotting function is being called the correct number of times, with the correct arguments, the contents of all plot cells are identical.  My suspicion is that I'm calling mutate() incorrectly, but I'm not sure.

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
library(ggplot2) 


dt = tribble(
  ~Type, ~Image,     ~Days, ~Case1_f, ~Case1_p, ~Case1_m, ~Case1_sd, ~Case2_x,
  "1-6",  "test.png", 1,    0.012345, 0.14,    0.54,     1.06, "1<br>2",
  "1-6",  "test.png", 2,    0.01,     0.74,    0.54,     1.06, "1\n2",
  "1-6",  "test.png", 3,    0.01,     0.74,    0.54,     1.06, "1\n2",
  "1-6",  "test.png", 4,    0.01,     0.74,    0.54,     1.06, "1\n2",
  "6-1",  "test.png", 1,    0.01,     0.74,    0.54,     1.06, "1\n2",
  "6-1",  "test.png", 2,    0.01,     0.14,    0.54,     1.06, "1\n2"
)

dt = dt %>%
  mutate(candlePlot = list(buildCandleDiagram(Type,8)))




buildCandleDiagram = function( openClose, levels ) {
  # levels = 8
  # openClose = "6-1"
  print(glue("Building candle diagram for {openClose}/{levels}"))
  
  v = str_split(openClose, "-")
  open = as.numeric( v[[1]][1] )
  close = as.numeric( v[[1]][2] )
  
  bottomH = min(open, close)
  topH = max(open, close)
  
  bottomL = bottomH - 1
  topL = topH - 1
  
  if (open < close) {
    color = "green"
  } else {
    color = "red"
  }
  
  g = 
    ggplot() + 
    # build body
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = bottomH/levels, ymax = topL/levels), 
              fill = color, color="black") +#, alpha = 0.4, color = "black") #+ 
    # build extra bodies
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = bottomL/levels, ymax = bottomH/levels), 
              fill = "gray", color="black") +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin =topL/levels, ymax = topH/levels), 
              fill = "gray", color="black") +  
    # build wicks
    geom_line(aes(x=c(0.5,0.5),y=c(0,bottomL/levels)), color="black") +
    geom_line(aes(x=c(0.5,0.5),y=c(topH/levels,1)), color="black") +
    # scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-5, 5)) #+
    theme_void()
  
  print(g)
  return(g)
}
```

Running the mutate gives the expected output:

```
Building candle diagram for 1-6/8
Building candle diagram for 1-6/8
Building candle diagram for 1-6/8
Building candle diagram for 1-6/8
Building candle diagram for 6-1/8
Building candle diagram for 6-1/8
```

But then:

```
> dt[1,'candlePlot'][[1]]
> dt[6,'candlePlot'][[1]]
```

give the plots for the first call, as though that output is being recycled.

Comment: Try using `purrr::map` or `lapply` inside your `mutate` to create the charts. It looks like it's generating the same list of charts for every row in the data frame, rather than one chart per row

Comment: Yeah, just do `dt %>% mutate(candlePlot = purrr::map(Type, buildCandleDiagram, 8))`

Comment: That's it guys, many thanks.  Clearly, I don't really know how mutate works after all (R keeps doing that to me).  Any explanation of why my original didn't work would be much appreciated! (I'm guessing that the list() did something else than just allowing me to add the plot to the cell?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue was resolved in the comments, however I just answered a similar question [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70704966/1829905) so I might as well share it here for the sake of closing this topic.

Basically the issue has to do with using `dplyr::mutate` on a vector, the column `Type`, rather than a single value. Per default, only the first value of the vector is used, which is why you get this result.

One option is to apply `mutate` row-wise, another one is to **vectorize** the function `buildCandleDiagram`, so it works both with single values and vectors. More detail in the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70704966/1829905).